# Windows XP: No audio, no master volume available or disabled, device and driver shows okay

Tags: windows-xp, audio, sound-card

I have here a Windows XP Prof machine (asus laptop A2D) with a onboard soundcard (Realtek AC97) that was working previously OK. On some moment the soundcard does not produces any sound and the most strange thing of all is that the Master Volume has disappeared from the settings and cannot get it back (because it is simply not there) only wave, SW-synthesizer and CD-player.

Also the properties window does not show any other options. In the device-manager there are no signs of errors. The Start|Settings|Configuration|Sound->volume tab shows me a volume slider that is disabled (gray) and I also cannot change the speaker settings.

What I have tried to try to solve this problem:

Reboot many times without effect

- Reinstall the drivers but doesn't solve the problem
- Tried an Creative USB MP3+ Soundcard and works okay
- Search the internet but doesn't find a solution.
- Restore SndVol32.exe from the install cd but does not help.
- ect.

Also test the device with another harddrive with Windows XP Home (original drive), with same driver and works okay. So there is no problem with the hardware.

Because the external Creative USB MP3+ Soundcard works okay and also the other XP Home installation works okay I think it has something to do with the registry. Maybe some "Volume Control" settings or properties are incorrect for this device/driver.

How can I restore these settings without reinstall Windows XP? I don't have the time to do that. Does anybody know a solution to this?

PS: I don't have a restore point because it is disabled on this machine. I don't think it has something to do with the driver or the device, it has something to do with Windows itself. Because there is no volume control, sounds won't play.

Anyone a solution to this?

Comment: Is the Windows Audio service running?

Comment: @randolph: Yes, that's running because the external USB audio device does work. Also checked it and it is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All right, it has something to do with the HAL settings of Windows. I wanted to change the computer type but was unable to do it via the device manager of Windows.

I found the solution here:

[http://falconfour.wordpress.com/2011/03/19/how-to-switch-windows-xp-hal-*back*-from-standard-pc-to-acpi-the-clean-way/](http://falconfour.wordpress.com/2011/03/19/how-to-switch-windows-xp-hal-_back_-from-standard-pc-to-acpi-the-clean-way/)

Let me explain:
My Windows XP was from another asus laptop that has died lately and want to use this image on a old laptop to rescue my WinXP installation (and to be able to access all my programs and settings before i buy a new one and to be able to DO something).

Because the ACPI stuff does not operate correctly on the died laptop (because battery was poor and some other problems) i decide to change it to standard-pc but cause problems (driver problems) on this old laptop. Changing it back to ACPI did the trick!

Performance is now superb (better than before) and soundcard is now working nicely.

Also, this proves that you can use another Windows XP installation on another computer ;-) without buying a new serial number from Microsoft.